# How to generate random 5 digit number with sequence on the end in java

Tags: java

Can someone please help to update my existing code, i need generate random 5 numbers with sequence on the end, for example use random 13543, but all next should be sequence like 13544,13545,13546,13547 etc.

```
int seq;
Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis() );
seq =  10000 + r.nextInt(20000);
String seqNo = String.valueOf(seq);
```

for now i have only random numbers

Comment: ok ... so keep track of a counter and add do seqNo += (counter+1) or similar

Comment: Paste _all_ your code - the only way to do this, is to store some state (your program will either do: "On startup, generate a random number, then, when my 'give me the next seqNo method is called, I shall take that number, increment it by 1, and return that", or: "On call, check if we generated a number before. If yes, increment and return it, if no, generate a random one").

Comment: you should store the 1st generated random somehow (for example in a static variable), and then just add +1 for every next.

Answer (score 2):

## `AtomicLong`

For [thread safety](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety), use [`AtomicLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html).

```
AtomicLong sequencer = new AtomicLong() ;
```

But you want to start with a random value rather than startingmat zero. So change that line to initialize with your random number from a [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html). Specify the range from which you want to randomly pick a number.

```
AtomicLong sequencer = new AtomicLong( ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong( 1 , 10_000 ) ) ;
```

Generate the next number, and return it with a call to [`incrementAndGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#incrementAndGet()).

```
long next = sequencer.incrementAndGet() ;
```

---

Use [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) if you are certain a 32-bit range of numbers suffices rather than the 64-bit range of `AtomicLong`.

Answer (score 0):

Just generate 1 random number and then print 4 number following in sequence

```
int seq;
Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
seq = 10000 + r.nextInt(20000); // generate random 5-digit number
System.out.println(seq); // print the first random number
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    System.out.println(seq + i); // print the next four numbers in sequence by adding 1
}
```

The output of the code will be a random 5-digit number followed by the next four numbers in sequence:

Example output:

```
19457
19458
19459
19460
19461
```